# Measuring treatment effect when only half the the treatment group appear affected

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cohens-d, differences

I have data for a set of customers divided into treatment and control, where the objective is to check the impact of treatment on customer’s bank balance.
 To this purpose, I computed the percentage change in balance ($) in a fixed interval before and after treatment. e.g., +20% for a customer whose balance in the pre-treatment interval was 10000 and post treatment 12000.
The table below indicates the percentage change values in the treatment and control groups by percentile. 
[image]

The chart below indicates the distribution of these percentage changes in the treatment (blue) and control (orange) groups respectively. Note the percentage rise is capped at 50% in the chart.
[image]

My inference based on the above observations is that the treatment does not matter for a certain fraction of the customers – ones with low engagement with the bank, whose balances either reduced or remained the same before and after treatment.
On the other hand, the treatment appears to have an impact on the customers who are growing their balances with the bank, the growth being higher for the treatment group as compared to control.
My objective is to quantify the impact of the treatment on balances. Can you suggest a statistical mean to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I think you may be looking for quantile regression.